# Retrieving the result of a task in Celery

Tags: django, redis, celery

I have a long running task in my Django application, and would like to display a progress bar and then output the task result to the user when finished.

I've found easily how to start the task and produce a progress bar via messaging, but how do I retrieve the results from the task once it's finished and display these to the user?

Using Redis as my message broker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a results backend in Celery.

The separate [django-celery-results](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#extensions) library will configure Django models as a result backend, and you can fetch the results from there.